# How to get Unicode for Chracter strings(UTF-8) in c or c++ language (Linux)

Tags: c++, c, unicode, utf-8

I am working on one application in which i need to know Unicode of Characters to classify them like Chinese Characters, Japanese Characters(Kanji,Katakana,Hiragana) , Latin , Greek  etc .

The given string is in UTF-8 Format.

If there is any way to know Unicode for UTF-8 Character? For example:

1. Character '≠' has U+2260 Unicode value.
2. Character '建' has U+5EFA Unicode value.

Comment: hi - how do you get the characters you want to classify? As picture? as utf-16? as code page coded character?

Comment: In a computer program you get to work with the Unicode code points. You don't program with the glyphs.

Comment: Tobias, It is in string  .... like 建光路 , 建贡路 for Chinese .... ; for Korean 수원 , 순천 etc .....

Comment: do you know how strings are stored in a computer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The utf-8 encoding is a variable width encoding of unicode. Each unicode code point can be encoded from one to four `char`.

To decode a `char*` string and extract a single code point, you read one byte. If the most significant bit is set then, the code point is encoded on multiple characters, otherwise it is the unicode code point. The number of bits set counting from the most-significant bit indicate how many `char` are used to encode the unicode code point.

This table explain how to make the conversion:

```
UTF-8 (char*)                       | Unicode (21 bits)
------------------------------------+--------------------------
0xxxxxxx                            | 00000000000000000xxxxxxx
------------------------------------+--------------------------
110yyyyy 10xxxxxx                   | 0000000000000yyyyyxxxxxx
------------------------------------+--------------------------
1110zzzz 10yyyyyy 10xxxxxx          | 00000000zzzzyyyyyyxxxxxx 
------------------------------------+--------------------------
11110www 10zzzzzz 10yyyyyy 10xxxxxx | 000wwwzzzzzzyyyyyyxxxxxx
```

Based on that, the code is relatively straightforward to write. If you don't want to write it, you can use a library that does the conversion for you. There are many available under Linux : [libiconv](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/), [icu](http://site.icu-project.org/), [glib](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/2.28/glib-Unicode-Manipulation.html#g-utf8-get-char), ...

Answer (score 1):

[libiconv](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/) can help you with converting the utf-8 string to utf-16 or utf-32. Utf-32 would be the savest option if you really want to support every possible unicode codepoint.